# unable to install microsoft.VSDesigner.Exception Assistant.smart Tag version 14

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2017, clickonce

I can't install a new version on new computer:

vs 2017 clickonce :unable to install microsoft.VSDesigner.Exception Assistant.smart Tag version 14[image]

I add all reference on another computer Every time i try i saw this message and i can't solve it,I try every thing it only run on my computer
any one can tell me how to solve it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved my issue,All you have to do is repair your visual studio 2017